# scikit-learn Classification of text documents ValueError: X and y have incompatible shapes

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, scikit-learn

I am trying to classify documents by category. I want to train several categories of data and then give it some text and have it tell me what category that text is in. For training I am using the 20 news groups. I get this error 
"ValueError: X and y have incompatible shapes X has 5 samples, but y has 4"   at classifier.fit(X_train, Y) .

Can anyone tell me how come X has 5 samples, X comes from data_train which is loading 4 categories? Also I would greatly appreciate any help in doing this a better way.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier



remove = ()

categories = [ 'alt.atheism', 'talk.religion.misc', 'comp.graphics', 'sci.space']


categories_test = ['sci.space' ]


print("Loading newsgroups dataset for categories:")

data_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories, shuffle=True,     random_state=42, remove=remove)

data_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test', categories=categories_test, shuffle=True, random_state=42, remove=remove)


X_test = data_test

X_train = data_train

y_train = data_train.target_names

lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()

Y = lb.fit_transform(y_train)

classifier = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()))])

classifier.fit(X_train, Y)

predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
all_labels = lb.inverse_transform(predicted)

for item, labels in zip(X_test.target_names, all_labels):
    print '%s => %s' % (item, ', '.join(labels))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is located here:

```
X_train = data_train
y_train = data_train.target_names
```

your data_train is an object, not an array of samples, so you are storing this object in `X_train`, while you want just input parameters (which are probably in the `.data` field of `data_train`). Also "target_names" are **names** of labels, not actual labels (which are stored in `.target` if I recall correectly)

it should be

```
X_train = data_train.data
y_train = data_train.target
```

the same applies to "data_test" naturally.

Comment: That returns 2034 I guess I need to know the sturcture of data_train.

Comment: and that ok, but your "Y" is also wrong., its ".target", not "target_names" as far as i remember

Comment: ... or `y_train = data_train.target_names[data_train.target]`.